# CSS ul li height Auto looks like Google Plus

Tags: css

same as title, i want css ul li look like this:

```
--------------------------
|           |            |
|           |            |
|  Block 1  |            |
|           |            |
|           |            |
------------|  Bloc 2    |
|           |            |
|           |            |
|           |            |
|  Block 3  |-------------
|           |            |
|           |            |
|           |            |
------------|  Block 4   |
            |            |          
            |            |
            |            |
            --------------
```

how i can do that? some body can help me?

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: It's not possible via CSS alone :( you can look at masonry js library

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a jquery grid plugin. There are tons out there. 
This is just an example from the first google results: http://gridster.net